# Laravel - Inserting & Updating Related Models

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

na documentação do Laravel ele ensina como fazer insert em models relacionadas. Segue exemplo que está na documentação: [Inserting & Updating Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)

```
$comment = new App\Comment(['message' => 'A new comment.']);    
$post = App\Post::find(1);    
$post->comments()->save($comment);
```

Em todos os exemplos da documentação ele faz o `find($id)` antes de salvar os dados nas `Model` relacionadas, foi assim que eu fiz:

```
$person = new Person;
$person->name = $request->input('name');
$person->cpf = $request->input('cpf');
$person->save();

$person = Person::find($person->id);

foreach ($request->input('phone') as $phone){
    $phones[] = new PersonPhone(['phone' => $phone]);
}
$person->phone()->saveMany($phones);
```

A tabela `person` possui uma relação de `hasMany` com a tabela `person_phone`. O método `phone()` retorna essa relação:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Person\PersonPhone','id_person', 'id');
```

Existe alguma forma de eu inserir tudo no banco sem fazer save e depois `find`? Procurei em toda documentação do Laravel e aqui no [StackOverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) e encontrei nada.

Comment: É só tirar a linha do find porque nesse caso é desnecessário, porque depois do save() você já tem o objeto Person se o save() retornar true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você já fez um objeto e chamou o método `save()` que retorna `true` se os dados forem salvo a linha após com `find` não é necessária porque você já tem um `Person` que precisa, modificação:

```
$person = new Person;
$person->name = $request->input('name');
$person->cpf = $request->input('cpf');
$person->save();
if ($person) // se for verdade que salvou os dados retorna true
{
    foreach ($request->input('phone') as $phone){
        $phones[] = new PersonPhone(['phone' => $phone]);
    }
    $person->phone()->saveMany($phones);
}
```

Lembrando que quando você precisa trabalhar com as relações de um Model, ele precisa de alguma forma estar presente em alguma variável, é que no seu caso faltou se atentar que você já tinha e não precisa chamar novamente.